Esper or Siddhi for Aggregation Event Processing and Scalability to a Large Number of Tasks
I have the following task: let's assume I'm developing an online store used by a million users. Users make purchases at different times. Each purchase by each user turns into a transaction event. I would like to process these events immediately, and if a user makes at least three more transactions within the next week or, for example, a month (a configurable time period), I want to give the user some kind of gift.
It seems that this task, and similar ones, could likely be implemented using event processing frameworks. I found complex event processing (CEP) engines called Esper and Siddhi and would like to ask whether it's possible to implement such a task with them. For example, when a user makes their first transaction, I want to assign a task to Esper/Siddhi to track the number of transactions made by this user from that moment over the course of a week. If the number of new transactions made by that user exceeds 3 within that week, Esper/Siddhi should generate an event for me.
The challenge is that a million users may make purchases at different times, and in the worst case, I'll need to assign Esper/Siddhi a million such tasks, each with a unique sliding time window (based on the time of their first transaction in the system). Is it possible to implement this in Esper or Siddhi, and can they scale to handle that many tasks?

Esper's horizontal scaling is a commercial product since its part of Esper Enterprise Edition. In Esper Enterprise Edition, horizontal scaling requires using Kafka. It scales by means of Kafka topic partitions, which Kafka assigns to worker processes.
